# ASP.NET vs Jquery.Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am trying to configure valication plugin to perform validation of ASP.NET generated form:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#aspnetForm").validate({
            rules: {
                "<%=ProjectName.ClientID%>": { required: true, minlength: 8 }
            },
            messages: {
                "<%=ProjectName.ClientID%>": { requred: "can not be empty", minlength: "type at least 8 chars" }

            },
            invalidHandler:
             function (form, validator) {
                 alert('validation failed!');
             },
            errorLabelContainer: $("#alert")
        });
    });
</script>
```

with HTML looking like this:

```
 <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="CreateProject.aspx"  
 onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_ShutUpPostbackButton')" 
 id="aspnetForm" enctype="MULTIPART/FORM-DATA">

 <input id="ctl00_JQueryContent_ProjectName" type="text" style="width:99%;" maxlength="50" name="ctl00$JQueryContent$ProjectName">


 </form>
```

For some reason the aformenetioned FORM tag has (after loading the page)

```
   novalidate="novalidate"
```

inclusion. I am clueless where it came from and if it interferes with my validation or not.

If I type INVALID one letter in the INPUT, plugin reacts by setting class="valid" to INPUT element, that is, something is working.

Besides getting this to work, I need to know how to disable/enable input elements (mainly buttons) depending on validation outcome. I know about invalidHandler, but what would be the handler for valid outcome? Please note that I need all validation to happen during typing.

Comment: The novalidate="novalidate"  is part of HTML5. Check your web.config to verify that the ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled settings are enabled.

Comment: @ema, I did that but novalidate did not go away.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute is added by jquery.validate plugin in case of HTML5 validation. It is in source (lines 32-33) of jquery.validate:

```
// Add novalidate tag if HTML5.
this.attr( "novalidate", "novalidate" );
```

You can remove this attribute. Look on this discussion: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-jquery-validate-when-html5-form-validation-is-present

Answer (score 0):

`submitHandler` is what gets triggered for a successfully validated form, and as you said, `invalidHandler` for unsuccessfully validated forms.